# When downloading, if the file already exists then prompt to open that file

Tags: firefox

Default behavior of my Firefox is that it downloads the files and automatically renames them.

If the file by the name already exists, the prompt would ideally give the options to

1. Open the existing file, or
2. Proceed with download and rename anyways. Is there an extension or setting which could achieve this?

My mode of use with Firefox is that I open a lot of tabs and then come back to them later.

Sometimes I have already downloaded a file in the past and I'd like to get an option to open the existing file instead of downloading a new one. This would save clutter and bandwidth.

Though a solution to this shouldn't be OS-dependent, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 if that matters.

Comment: Welcome :- ) Are you asking us to recommend a plug-in? if so then you should ask at out sister site [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Btw, in Windows, the "save as" dialog warns if the file exists, in which case I just double click it. Not quite what you want, but it works :-)

Comment: Not necessarily looking for a plugin to do this. If this was a webpage-only matter I'd be happy to script in the functionality myself using greasemonkey. Since this is to optimize my workflow (and might be a common need), I asked on super user. The prompt to save as doesn't let you open files it seems, so doesn't work

Comment: then you asked at the correct site (but at least you learned about s/w recommendations; we do a lot of programming tool questions there :-) I was certain that the file save dialog would let you double click. Maybe right click & run? I do know for certain that I can delete from that prompt, as I occasionally see a stray "new folder" lying around while saving & delete it. If you do code a solution, please consider githubbing it & posting an answer here. Good luck

Comment: Update. I just tried to save this page, double-clicked on a text file & got "do you want to overwrite", ***BUT*** I could right-click & "Open". The full context menu is there, but "open" ought to do it. What do you think? Good enough to save you some coding?

Comment: Doesn't work in Ubuntu 16.04 using Unity. The open option is greyed out if you right click. I'll add that information to the question. Even if it did work, it's not a good solution considering that your "save file" dialog would still remain open after the file opens

Comment: Sorry, I am using Windows :-(

Comment: It's alright. I think a clean solution to this would be OS Independent.